# Couchbase Bucket closing with ExecutorService

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, couchbase

I am using **Couchbase** Java SDK version `2.3.1` in a Spring 4.x environment. When I execute the code with a single thread, everything is fine. When the code runs within Executor service with multiple threads, I get the **Bucket Closed Exception**. The java classes are shown below:

Class: **AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.demo")
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean(name = BeanNames.CONFIGS)
  @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
  public Configs configs() {
    // initialize the app configs.
  }

  @Bean(name = BeanNames.COUCHBASE_BUCKET)
  @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
  public Bucket couchbaseBucket() {
    Bucket bucket = null;
    try {
      final DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.Builder envBuilder = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder();
      // Set the properties

      final CouchbaseEnvironment couchbaseEnv = envBuilder.build();
      final Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(couchbaseEnv, nodes);
      bucket = cluster.openBucket(bucketName, bucketPassword);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      logger.error("Exception while configuring Couchbase bucket....", e);
      throw new IllegalStateException("Couchbase cannot be configured.");
    }
  }
}
```

Class: **CouchbaseDAO.java**

```
@Component(BeanNames.COUCHBASE_DAO)
public class CouchbaseDAO {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier(BeanNames.COUCHBASE_BUCKET)
  private Bucket bucket;

  public String getByKey(final String key) {
    final JsonDocument jsonDocument = bucket.get(key);
    if (jsonDocument != null && jsonDocument.content() != null) {
      return Objects.toString(jsonDocument.content());
    }

    return null;
  } 
}
```

Class: **DataCollector.java**

```
@Component(BeanNames.DATA_COLLECTOR)
public class DataCollector {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier(BeanNames.COUCHBASE_DAO)
  private CouchbaseDAO dao;

  public void doCollect(key) {
    // Call DAO to get doc.
    final String doc = dao.getByKey(key);

    // ... do other things
  }
}
```

Class: **AppTask.java**

```
public class AppTask implements Runnable {
  private final dataCollector;

  public AppTask(DataCollector dataCollector) {
    this.dataCollector = dataCollector;  
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      // Get Couchbase key

      dataCollector.doCollect(key);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // This is printing Couchbase bucket closed exception
      logger.error("Uncaught exception...", e);
    }
  }
}
```

Class: **AppExecutor.java**

```
@Component(BeanNames.APP_TASK_EXECUTOR)
public class AppTaskExecutor {
  private final ExecutorService executor;
  private final Configs configs;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier(BeanNames.DATA_COLLECTOR)
  private DataCollector dataCollector;

  @Autowired
  public AppTaskExecutor(@Qualifier(BeanNames.CONFIGS) final Configs configs) {
    this.configs = configs;
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(configs.taskCount());
  }

  public void execute() {
    for (int i = 0; i < configs.count(); i++) {
      executor.submit(new AppTask(dataCollector));
    }
  }
}
```

Class: **MainApp.java**

```
public class MainApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (final ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ConnectorSpringConfig.class)) {

    final AppExecutor appExecutor = applicationContext.getBean(BeanNames.APP_TASK_EXECUTOR, AppExecutor.class);
    appExecutor.execute();
  }
}
```

The stack trace I am seeing in my log file is:

```
com.couchbase.client.core.BucketClosedException: SLP has been closed
    at com.couchbase.client.core.RequestHandler.dispatchRequest(RequestHandler.java:206)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.RequestHandler.onEvent(RequestHandler.java:176)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.RequestHandler.onEvent(RequestHandler.java:71)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:129)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there anything wrong with the configuration or organization of components?

I tried with following changes:

- Changed the number of threads to **1** and it works without that exception.

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the stack trace? Is the Dao or collector doing anything else with the bucket?

Comment: @SimonBaslé I have added the stack trace to my question. Please see if that helps. And, this is the only trace in my log file (I am running the app at `DEBUG` level).

Comment: ok so that doesn't tell much unfortunately... can you double check that you're not closing/disconnecting either the `Cluster` object or the `Bucket` itself anywhere? maybe if you can reproduce locally, put a breakpoint on bucket's `close()` method, see if it is called early in the bean's lifecycle?

Comment: I found the issue; its in `try-with-resource` construct. Since the method boundary was ending at `appExecutor.execute()` (they are basically background tasks), Spring was calling `close()` on `ConfigurableApplicationContext` which by contract was releasing all underlying resources. This is only logical reason which I found a good fit. I removed the `try-with-construct` and it started working as expected.